# ASP.NET Dependency Injection error: Some services are not able to be constructed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, repository

I created an .NET MVC application and made use of Dependency Injection and Repository Pattern However, I am getting an error when i am trying to POST data to database (Other CRUD methods like Get, GetSingle, Update and Detele works fine):

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType: FluentHibernateTest.IBookService Lifetime: Scoped
> ImplementationType: FluentHibernateTest.Models.BookService': Unable to resolve service for type
> 'FluentHibernateTest.Models.IRepository' while attempting to activate 'FluentHibernateTest.Models.BookService'.)'

**NhibernateHelper.cs**

```cs
public static class NhibernateHelper
{
    public static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory { get; private set; }
    public static Configuration configuration { get; set; }

    //static string _connectionstring;
    public static void InitializeConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .Driver<MicrosoftDataSqlClientDriver>()
                .ConnectionString(connectionString).ShowSql)
            .Mappings(m => m
            .FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Book>())
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

**BookController.cs**

```cs
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Book Book)
{
    try
    {
        Book newBook = _IbookService.AddBook(Book);
        return new ObjectResult(newBook);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

**Repository.cs**

```cs
ISession _session;

public Repository(ISession session)
{
    _session = session;
}

 public Book AddBook(Book Book)
{
    return _session.Save(Book) as Book;
}
```

**BookService.cs**

```cs
private readonly IRepository _repository;

public BookService(IRepository repository)
{
    this._repository = repository;
}

public Book AddBook(Book Book)
{
    Book entity = null;
    entity = _repository.AddBook(Book);
    return entity;
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddScoped<IBookService,BookService>();
    services.AddScoped<IBookController, BookController>();
    services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
}
```

Comment: I Would Try and Add your IRepository as a Singleton, Scoped Will Share the same instance locally but create multiple instances.

Comment: @Retic Can you provide an example please?

Comment: services.AddSingleton<IRepository, Repository>(); Instead of services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();

Comment: @Retic thanks for the try, but didnt work

Comment: @Retic That is likely a really dangerous idea and will absolutely not fix the problem here.

Comment: Was Just a thought.  I did not have the Time to test an Implementation myself.

Comment: Please check to see whether the registered `IRepository` is **the exact same type** as the `IRepository` that is referenced from `BookService`. The most likely cause is that you (accidentally) created a second type called `IRepository` (i.e. `FluentHibernateTest.Models.IRepository`, which is a different type from the one you registered using `AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>()`.